# How can I make my .NET or Crystal Reports editable? Is there any way to print the custom positioned text?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to make a report, in which I want that user must be able to reposition the labels, text or images with his own choice. I am actually making a cheque maker software in Windows Forms .NET 4, and for different banks there needs different positions but same attributes, because we have to print on cheques of different banks so each one has different position of signature field, name field, money field, etc. So is there any option in any report or Crystal Reports that once we generate a report, we may able to move the labels with drag and drop, and can we adjust the text by drag and drop once the report is shown in the report viewer?

Comment: Can anyone provide me link for designing project of .net windows forms, which have the ability to reposition the text and images with drag n drop, if report does not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not want to use report generation for check printing.  Check printing is "forms" generation, not "report" generation.  They're fundamentally different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Once the report is generated, the user won't be able to adjust its fields' locations.

Keeping this in mind, you have a few options:

- You could, however, group the report by bank, then add a section for each bank's fields and positioning.  Use a conditional suppression formula on each section to show the section for the related bank.  If you have a lot of clients (50+), this approach might be a bit hard to maintain.
- CR does support some limited field positioning based on conditional logic (X and width), but it may not be as flexible as you need.  You'd probably want to keep the fields' location in a table so that you could (attempt) to use this to position the fields when the report is generated.
- use the report-application server (RAS) SDK--it has finely-grained control of report elements.